# How does node.js version numbers work and how do I ensure compatibility?

Tags: node.js, versioning

What is the versioning style of the project?

Comment: Wow. Super useful and still relevant even today, almost a decade on. Thanks for asking.

Comment: Funny how it says the question is irrelevant to most users. Here I am in 2023 pondering about node versions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should only be using even numbered versions: `x.[even].z`. These are all "stable" and bug fixes will be released to them (until the next minor version). Only the latest `x.[even].z` version is supported at any given time.

For compatibility, you should just look at the documentation. For example, for events: http://nodejs.org/api/events.html

> Stability: 4 - API Frozen

That means you can be rest assured that the EventEmitter class will never change.

Then there's stuff like [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) where no one is sure what they're doing, and you probably shouldn't be using it:

> Stability: 1 - Experimental

Your best best is just to stick with `Stability >= 3` features and not worry about compatibility between versions.

Also, there doesn't seem to be a strict release cycle.

Comment: So, basically every time a new major even release is out my software based in the previous major release get unsupported and I'm force to migrate?

Comment: For most things the API will stay the same like http. If you use frameworks like Express and Connect, they will handle some API changes for you. Just don't use experimental features. There's also no one forcing you to upgrade; you can skip every other even release if you'd like.

Comment: You said "There's also no one forcing you to upgrade", but is insane run an enterprise level app based on a tech that is not supported, so, I feel that if I used node.js, I'm pretty much forced to update every time they release a new stable version, don't you think? Thanks again for your reply Jonathan.

Comment: If I were you, I would just wait to upgrade. For example, wait until 0.10.10 instead up upgrading to 0.10.0 immediately. 2 versions back isn't a big deal, but 3 is. And again, if you only use stable features, then upgrading shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I got it, thanks again Ong.

Answer (score 5):

Node has a two-track versioning system. Even-numbered versions (0.4, 0.6, 0.8) are stable, and odd-numbered versions are unstable. The stable releases are API-stable, which means that if you are using 0.8.1 and 0.8.2 comes out, you should be able to upgrade with no issues.

On the 0.9.x stream, any update may change the API, especially in parts of the system that are under active development. When the odd-version reaches a certain level of stability and maturity, it becomes the next even-version.

Comment: Thanks Mark... and what is the support scheme for even-numbered versions? and its release cycle? I mean, they have a timed release process or what?

Answer (score 1):

There is not a strict timed-release cycle. The primary maintainer of Node.JS is a guy named Isaac Schleuter and he has been very public about his goals and targets with node. He is also open to a lot of community input on this, so they run NodeConf and Node Summer Camp and some other events to gather input.

If you have time to really dig into the community, check out the [NodeUp podcast](http://nodeup.com/) and some of Isaac's talks to get an idea about the direction they are going and APIs.

You ask about version 1.0. As far as I remember, Isaac has a couple of specific things he wants to stabilize before going to version 1.0. In particular, I remember Streams and Buffers which have really become key to node's growth. (*that's stated, this just from memory*)