# npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react js and I get these warning messages when creat-react-app.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'expect@29.0.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.9.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'pretty-format@29.0.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.9.0', npm: '8.19.2' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/expect-utils@29.0.3',
```

Someone provided a solution here:
[Cause of npm WARN EBADENGINE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269056/cause-of-npm-warn-ebadengine/73835062#73835062)
but my problem is my package.json file does'nt come with engines in it and package-lock.json comes with thousands, and it is difficult to figure out which one needs to change. Any idea how could I solve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're using node 17.x which is an unstable version that is not supported. Even versions are stable, odd versions are unstable.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790017/how-does-node-js-version-numbers-work-and-how-do-i-ensure-compatibility